# Node.js Capabilities for Operating System

Tags: node.js

What node.js can do on the operating system level?

Like can we building something in node which can control graphic card or speaker, or other device connected via usb?

Comment: You don't need to work on "the operating system level" to access those. The job of the OS is to make accessing those devices easy - and if node.js is any good you should be able to do so.

Answer (score 3):

[libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) provides the low-level support for node.js.  For anything not available through the node core directly, you can write modules in C++ (linking against the libusb library directly) or use an existing module like https://npmjs.org/package/usb

Answer (score 1):

There's a full list of the builtin modules [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). There aren't that many of them to skim through yourself. Most of what you want to do is not built in.

However, if you know C or C++, you can write your own [addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that expose native objects to the JS layer. So anything you could ever want to do is possible.

And someone may have already written an [npm](https://npmjs.org) package for it, so you don't have to. But nobody is going to summarize all 43326 packages to tell you "What node.js can do". You will have to ask for something specific, and search for it yourself.

Comment: you're linking this question to this question :)

Comment: @gustavohenke: Just emphasizing how important recursion is in Javascript. :) Good catch; should be fixed now.